# How can I throw errors with custom error messages?

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling

I have a function that allocates a text font on the heap from a filename. It looks like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<sf::Font> newFont(std::string&& fileName)
{
    auto font = std::make_unique<sf::Font>();
    if (!font->loadFromFile(fileName))
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    return font;

}
```

Someone on Stack Exchange - Code Review told me that I needed better error messages, since my program just silently exits if the file is not found. But since I'm writing a game, I'm not using a console window for output. I was thinking that maybe I could throw some kind of custom compiler error that triggers when the file is not found. Something like "Unable to allocate font: <font_path>". Is there a way to do this, or should I solve this some other way?

Comment: How would a compiler error help? The game doesn't know whether it can load the font until it runs. It doesn't know that when it compiles.

Comment: Often you write a descriptive message to a log file for later inspection, and then exit the program.

Comment: You can throw an exception and catch it in the int main() for your application and display a GUI popup window with the error message.

Comment: First, learn the difference between compile time when the compiler gives you warnings and error messages and runtime, when your program executes and maybe throws exceptions. These are completely different things, and you should not mix them up.

Comment: "I'm not using a console window for output" - but presumably you're using something else for output, so you need to connect whatever mechanism propagates error info out of your function to whatever output technology you use. Maybe that's a message box popup on the screen. Maybe you implement your own kind of in-game console log. Maybe you write stuff to a auxiliary log file on disk. What kind of output you choose depends on your exact situation as well as what kinds of errors you want to go where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions are what you are looking for:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<sf::Font> newFont(std::string&& fileName) noexcept(false)
{
    auto font = std::make_unique<sf::Font>();
    if (!font->loadFromFile(fileName))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unable to allocate font: " + fileName);
    }
    return font;
}
```

Now we can print error messages using a `try`-`catch` block:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<sf::Font> font;
    try {   
        font = newFont("myfont.ttf");
    } catch ( const std::exception & ex ) {
        PRINT_ERROR(ex.what());
        return 1;
    }
    // do something with font ...
}
```

Normally you could implement `PRINT_ERROR` by just printing to `std::cerr`, but since you don't have a console to print to, you will need to do something else with the error message. Options include:

- creating a log file and printing errors to the log using `std::ofstream`
- displaying the error messages directly in your game